# CSS/Javascript multiple div flip with class's and id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a bit new at CSS/Javascript (really don't know much about Javascript at all). I'm trying to flip multiple div's on the same page, using code I've found elsewhere ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ee8nvda/)) and modifying for my own needs.

Right now, my problem is that if I click a div to flip it, other div's on the page flip as well. I have looked through this site, and understand that I can't use `class`, I have to use an `id`. I have tried to do so, but I can't seem to get it to work at all. I'm wondering if my Javascript needs to be tweaked?

My sample code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q276yL4k/). Ideally, I'd like to keep as much of this Javascript as possible, because content on either side of the div's that are flipping will be different sizes, and this Javascript solves that small problem.

Any suggestions/hints/ideas as to how to put an id in each div to ensure that they will flip individually would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you going to a flip multiple cards, you need to make a few changes. There is a variation of your code in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/8xm3qyzp/).

I simplified the HTML a little. The keys are:

1) Give the boxes to flip a class of "flip-it" instead of an ID, since there is only supposed to be one ID "flip-it" on a page. Then the code to invoke is:

```
$('div.flip-it').hover(flipThis);
```

2) Then in flipThis, you need to determine which card is to be flipped. Your old code flipped all of them. The relevant changes are:

```
function flipThis() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var card = $this.find('.flipcard');
    var front =  $this.find('.flipcard-front');
    var back =  $this.find('.flipcard-back');
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Just messing around now, but if I wanted to introduce a button or even a hyperlink to do the flip instead of a hover, would I change the Javascript to `$('div.flip-it').click(flipThis);`, then move the `flip-it`class to act on the button or hyperlink instead?

Comment: The function flipThis would need some way of knowing which div to flip. So, for example, if you had a link with id #link to flip a card with id #card, you would need something like '$('#link"),click(function() { flipThis('#card') });' and adjust flipThis to work from a passed id.  There are lots of variations, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use classes. The javascript-function `flipThis` is now called when you hover over a div with the id 'flip-it'. But you gave each div the same ID, therefore all of them flipped. In addition, the HTML-code was faulty (missing some closing div tags `</div>`).

Here I fixed these HTML-errors and I changed the functionality back to using classes: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/q276yL4k/3/

The key is using `this` in the `flipThis`-function. Since the function is called on an event, `this` will contain the element that is hovered upon. You can then select just this element (so not all elements with a certain class):

```
var card = $(this).find('.flipcard');
var front = $(this).find('.flipcard-front');
var back = $(this).find('.flipcard-back');
```

Finally, to have elements floating and then changing the height gives problems in positioning of the flip-cards. The third flipcard will appear on the right of the first flipcard if the height of the second flipcard changes. To overcome this problem, you need to put an element in between that 'clears' the float. I used a div with a 'clearer' class. The CSS of this class is simply:

```
.clearer {
    clear: both;
}
```